# How to get the APP Version using a Pre-Render APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm trying to get the app version so I can log it in a table when inserting or updating data.

I'm currently doing this for `APP_USER` and `sysdate` which is working fine.

PL/SQL Code:

[image: PL/SQL Code]

I would also like to add the Name and Version.

I tested `APP_NAME` and that does work, but `APP_Version` returns nothing?

I was also wondering what other `APP_` variables are available?

Comment: http://semibyte.de/informatics/oradb/apex-built-in-variablen/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What better place to start than... [the official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.1/htmdb/using-substitution-strings.html) ? A full list of all substitution variables is available. However, not all substitution variables exist in every context. According to the docs, APP_VERSION can only be referenced as #APP_VERSION# - that is the syntax used in templates. In a pl/sql context or html context this variable is not available.

A simple workaround is to create an application item G_APP_VERSION (or however you want to name it) and populate it using a computation (Type: SQL Query (return single value)) with source:

```
select version from apex_applications where application_id = :APP_ID
```

Then you can reference this variable in your pl/sql code.

Comment: I tried that option and got the following error?    ERR-1002 Unable to find item ID for item "G_APP_VERSION" in application "111".
Unexpected error, unable to find item name at application or page level.

Technical Info (only available for developers)
is_internal_error: true
apex_error_code: WWV_FLOW.FIND_ITEM_ID_ERR
component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_COMP
component.id: 19536833986925817
component.name: G_APP_VERSION
error_backtrace

Comment: Did you create the application item ?

Comment: You need to create the application item first (text says "create an application item") . Then create computation on it. That error message seems to indicate that the application item does not exist.

Comment: I just added the application item as well, works now.  Helps if you follow directions.  thanks

Comment: I'll try to put it more explicit next time :)